# How to select previous input element outside current div but with same parent div

Tags: jquery

My HTML code is:

```html
<div id="subjects">
  <div class="group">
    <label for="n1">1. Name</label>
    <div class="child">
      <input type="text" name="" id="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label for="n2">2. Name</label>
    <div class="child">
      <input type="text" name="" id="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label for="n3">3. Name</label>
    <div class="child">
      <input type="text" name="" id="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All I want is if I click second or third input element and if previous one is empty an alert box must be show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$(".required-input").click(function() {
  $($(".required-input").get().reverse()).each(function() {
    if($(this).val() === "") {
      $(this).focus();
      return;
    }
  })
})
```

and you need to add this custom class on your inputs:

```
  <div id="subjects">
    <div class="group">
      <label for="n1">1. Name</label>
      <div class="child">
        <input type="text" name="" class="required-input" id="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <label for="n2">2. Name</label>
      <div class="child">
        <input type="text" name="" class="required-input" id="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <label for="n3">3. Name</label>
      <div class="child">
        <input type="text" name="" class="required-input" id="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/uQJMNEGxEjDnewkXp5wr?p=preview

Comment: works great. plz could you explain this code bcz i'm newer. adv. thanx

Comment: Everytime you click on some input with class "required-input", this will loop for every input marked with this class and focus on the first blank input or the current if all is filled.

Comment: Ryan, there are many ways to do something.. My solution works as expected. Sorry if you don't like.

Comment: I would appreciate your vote to clean Ryan's negative vote ;)

Comment: anyway.. have a nice day

Comment: I did it before your call

Answer (score 3):

```
$('input').on('click', function() {
  var index = $('#subjects input').index(this);

  if (index > 0 && $('#subjects input').eq(index-1).val() == '')
    alert("Previous input is empty");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bdvte1cm/1/

Comment: if we put some text in first input element and then click second one still an alert is shown

Comment: Your solution isn't working... I just filled the previous and the alert appears for me..

Comment: I wouldn't suggest you to do what you did.. many things in the world can be done on many different ways... for sure solutions are better than others but we need good sense to rate what solutions are horribles.. anyway... I'm here to help people and I suppose you are too... Let's help more people! ;)

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is add the `id`s for all the inputs. The next would be looping through the inputs. May be this is not scalable, but this works if the number of inputs are less:

```js
$(function () {
  $("input:text").focus(function () {
    myID = this.id;
    $("input").each(function () {
      if (this.id == myID)
        return;
      if (this.value.trim().length == 0)
        alert("Please fill the previous one.");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="subjects">
  <div class="group">
    <label for="n1">1. Name</label>
    <div class="child">
      <input type="text" name="n1" id="n1" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label for="n2">2. Name</label>
    <div class="child">
      <input type="text" name="n2" id="n2" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label for="n3">3. Name</label>
    <div class="child">
      <input type="text" name="n3" id="n3" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second Attempt:

```js
$(function () {
  $("input:text").focus(function () {
    myID = this.id;
    for (i = 1; i < parseInt(myID[1]); i++)
      if ($("#n" + i).val().trim().length == 0) {
        alert("Please fill the previous one.");
        return;
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="subjects">
  <div class="group">
    <label for="n1">1. Name</label>
    <div class="child">
      <input type="text" name="n1" id="n1" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label for="n2">2. Name</label>
    <div class="child">
      <input type="text" name="n2" id="n2" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label for="n3">3. Name</label>
    <div class="child">
      <input type="text" name="n3" id="n3" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: infinite alerts ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML has some lacks:

when you specify a label like:

```
<label for="n1">1. Name</label>
```

the corresponding input field must be:

```
<input type="text" name="" id="n1" />
```

The id cannot be void or different from the for attribute of label.

The snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  // for each input except the first one, when you click...
  $('#subjects').find(':text:gt(0)').on('click', function(e) {
    // get the first input
    var firstEle = $('#subjects').find(':text:eq(0)');
    // check if it's empty
    if (firstEle.val().length == 0) {
      alert('empty');
      firstEle.focus();
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>


<div id="subjects">
    <div class="group">
        <label for="n1">1. Name</label>
        <div class="child">
            <input type="text" name="" id="n1" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <label for="n2">2. Name</label>
        <div class="child">
            <input type="text" name="" id="n2" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <label for="n3">3. Name</label>
        <div class="child">
            <input type="text" name="" id="n3" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```